# Sending email from a home server centos 6.4

Tags: centos

We have a centos 6.4 server at home with dynamic ip with no domain name. We know normally the IPS will block port 25. We need to test the server to send out email to my own email accounts like gmail or yahoo. How to go about it to tweak it? The email can be even @localhost we dont mind as long it can send out email to our email boxes.

My current java application codes.

```
Properties props = new Properties();        
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "*******");       
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "26");      
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");      
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "26");        
      mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator()
      {             
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
        {                   
        return new PasswordAuthentication("*******","********");                
        }       
      });
      transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
      transport.connect(emailUsername, emailPassword);
      }
```

Comment: If your ISP blocks 25 port you could try to use 587/465 instead. Note: gmail will block email from localhost/localdomain or from nonexistent domain

Comment: @Alex how about other mail like yahoo? Will it still block? Which is should I use sendmail or postfix because I google some ask me to remove and install postfix.

Comment: I think yes, yahoo and other BIG mail provider will block such emails. Which MTA to use postfix/exim/sendmail/qmail it doesn't matter. You could try to use dyndns.

Comment: @what is dyndns you mean get to dynamic dns first is it?

Comment: Yes, I mean to use dynamic dns, for example http://changeip.org/

Comment: please rephrase your question more clearly instead of "How to go about it to tweak it?"

Comment: @In what sense should I rephrase ? I dont quite get it how should I rephrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to port 587 or 465 of gmail/yahoo as suggested by @ALex_hha. Just make sure you configure your MTA to use remote smtp authentication. That depends for each MTA and remote email service. For example, this article describes how to connect postfix to gmail: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:loyCTx-lYuIJ:ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/11/11/relaying-postfix-smtp-via-smtpgmailcom/&hl=en&strip=1

Alternatively you can request your ISP to unblock port 25 if you are able to provide them with a good reason (I've asked mine with success) BUT you will need to configure a VALID email domain on the MTA when you send emails to the world. Sending emails with addresses like `sender@localhost` will result in your email getting refused/marked as spam almost 100% of the time.

Comment: Costin I am kind of lost with MTA and MUA difference? With you method how does it work? MY source email will be @gmail.com ? Does this method have limitation on how many email could be sent ?

Comment: yes, your originating email will be your gmail address. you will have to comply with gmail rules in regard with rate of emails.

Comment: mta = the transport agent (or what is sometimes called "email server") while mua = the user agent (or what is sometimes called "email client"). a MTA can also behave as a MUA (in the example given in the article when postfix connects to gmail)

Comment: Ok in this case my server will be MTA right? Is there any other option beside using gmail as I know gmail is very strict and I plan to send more then few hundred email per minute just for a trial and stress test my java application.

Comment: you can instruct postfix to limit the number of simultaneous deliveries or messages per time unit, while at the same time accepting emails from your java application. it will keep them into queue and deliver them as soon as possible.

Comment: I have updated my question with my current java application codes which just purely sends out email it does not takes in any incoming email as its purely just alerting email. So here is where we want to stress the application to see how many we can send out. Currently we are using a proper email server but we want to replicate the whole process on a local server.

Comment: You can setup your own email server for domain example.net. If you just want to know - how many emails will sends your application

Comment: @Alex I think I am gonna setup my own email server. I notice using postfix is quite good.